# PYOMO spreadsheet reading issue

Tags: python, spreadsheet, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

We have a model that uses Dataportal of Pyomo to read parameter from several csv files. On a Windows laptop we are running into the following error while this is not replicable on another computer. Any ideas what might be missing in this setting?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/stianbac/OneDrive - NTNU/EMPIRE/EMPIRE in Pyomo/EMPIRE_Pyomo_version_4/Empire_draft4.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/stianbac/OneDrive - NTNU/EMPIRE/EMPIRE in
>   Pyomo/EMPIRE_Pyomo_version_4')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/stianbac/OneDrive - NTNU/EMPIRE/EMPIRE in
>   Pyomo/EMPIRE_Pyomo_version_4/Empire_draft4.py", line 107, in 
>       instance = model.create_instance(data)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\DataPortal.py",
>   line 138, in load
>       self.connect(**kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\DataPortal.py",
>   line 98, in connect
>       self._data_manager.open()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\plugins\data\sheet.py",
>   line 54, in open
>       self.sheet = ExcelSpreadsheet(self.filename, ctype=self.ctype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\excel\spreadsheet.py",
>   line 79, in **new**
>       return ExcelSpreadsheet_win32com(*args, **kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\excel\spreadsheet_win32com.py",
>   line 59, in **init**
>       self.open(filename, worksheets, default_worksheet)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\excel\spreadsheet_win32com.py",
>   line 80, in open
>       self._ws[wsid] = self.wb.Worksheets.Item(wsid)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\stianbac\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
>   line 516, in **getattr**
>       ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
>
> com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)

Here is the entry of the code:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
#from pyomo.core.expr  import current as EXPR
#import numpy as np
import math
import csv
model = AbstractModel()
model.Nodes = Set()
model.Generators = Set() #g
...
data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='Sets.xlsx',range='B1:B53',using='xlsx',format="set", set=model.Generators)
data.load(filename='Sets.xlsx',range='nodes',using='xlsx',format="set", set=model.Nodes)
...
instance = model.create_instance(data)
...
```

Comment: This looks difficult to troubleshoot. While you're waiting, is it possible to work around this using pandas?

Comment: I have seen such messages with versions of Excel that were not yet properly licensed and activated.